# Why does the compiler complain about this `sprintf` argument?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf

The following code used to compile fine. I migrated the project to a new version and now the compiler is complaining about one of my `sprintf` arguments. Here is the warning:

```
warning: format '%02d' expects type 'int', but argument 12 has type 'double'
```

FYI, the IDE is MPLAB X 2.35 and the compiler is XC 1.34. I have optimizations turned off and I have tried clean/build. I can only suspect that maybe the struct alignment is out of whack. I am hoping I am just missing the obvious, such as not being able to count.

Offending code:

```
typedef struct _AnalysisEvent
{
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned char year;
    unsigned char hour;
    unsigned char minute;
    unsigned char second;
    unsigned int duration;
    double min;
    double max;
    double avg;
} AnalysisEvent;

AnalysisEvent AnalysisEvents[ANALYSIS_MAX_COUNT][ANALYSIS_EVENTS_MAX_COUNT];

unsigned char AnalysisEventGetValueStrAlt(unsigned short id, unsigned char index, char *buffer, int length)
{
    if (Analysis[id].count > index)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "Analysis ID: %d\r\nEvent ID: %d\r\nMin: %.2f\r\nMax: %.2f\r\nAvg: %.2f\r\nTime: %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\r\nDuration: %d\r\n",
                id,
                index,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].min,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].max,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].avg,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].month,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].day,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].year,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].hour,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].min,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].second,
                AnalysisEvents[id][index].duration
                );
        return index;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `xpects type 'int', but argument 12 has type 'double'` -- which part is unclear?

Comment: `AnalysisEventGetValueStrAlt` is passed a `length` parameter which I assume specifies the length of `buffer`, but you never use it. It would be much better to use `snprintf` and pass it there.

Comment: I agree that it would be better, but the problem is that snprintf doesn't append a null terminator. I could do that manually. I normally check that the length is adequate to fit the contents and return an error if the buffer size isn't sufficient without copying any characters into the buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argument 12 is:

```
AnalysisEvents[id][index].min,
```

You probably want:

```
AnalysisEvents[id][index].minute,
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something obvious. I was looking at the last argument, `duration` as being the problem, not even considering that it was `minute`. Thanks so much. Side note: curious why the compiler didn't catch this and complain about it in the previous project. Maybe warnings were suppressed.

Comment: @Psyfun As Sourav mentioned, when the compiler warns about a particular parameter, it means the total number of parameters to the function, not the number of `printf` format parameters.

Comment: Good point. I think this led me down the wrong path. I probably would have realized that I used the wrong structure member had I considered what the error was actually telling me and looked at parameter 12 instead of 14.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the offending part is

```
 %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\r\
                      ^^^
```

The corresponding argument is `AnalysisEvents[id][index].min`, type double. You used `%d`.

FWIW, maybe the answer **you want** is

*"the argument number in the warning message is the total of the ones supplied to `sprintf()`, counting from `buffer` itself, not only the ones supplied as the argument to the format."*